# What is the technical term for a value which can be either a scalar or an array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, naming

I'm working with the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org) format, which has the notion of a `data` property which can hold either a scalar (single) or array (multiple) value. I'm writing code for encoding and decoding into the format, and when naming my types, was trying to come up with a good name for such types of values. In TypeScript, it would be

```
type Poly<T> = T | T[];
```

For your information, here is the relevant part of the JSON API doc (my emphasis):

> Primary data MUST be **either**:
>       a **single** resource object, a single resource identifier object, or null, for requests that target single resources
>       an **array** of resource objects, an array of resource identifier objects, or an empty array ([]), for requests that target resource collections

As an example, here is a mapping function for such mutant values:

```
function polymap<T, U>(data: Poly<T>, fn: (input: T) => U, thisArg?: any): Poly<U> {
  if (data instanceof Array) return (data as T[]).map(fn, thisArg);
  return fn.call(thisArg, data as T);
}
```

Anyway, as you can see, I'm going with "poly", but is there any established terminology for this, or other good suggestions?

Comment: I believe the TypeScript terminology is the one from computer science - union type. Of course union types does refers to much more than T | T[]

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of union types, I was looking for something for this particular case.

Comment: It is interesting that this type of question will not get a "no established terminology" answer even if it is the correct answer. If the term exists someone will answer but if it does not how can anyone be sure that it does not exist as opposed to him not knowing it? :)

Comment: Can't think of a name but more importantly, it's a bad practice that introduces complexity and can trick api users. Just send an Array of 1 element instead.

Comment: @AlexG I agree in principle, but this notion of either-scalar-or-array is baked into the API I am dealing with.

Comment: you may say categorical or Functor

Comment: If you know whether you are targeting a collection of resources or a single resource then you can discard the whole notion and have different return types for each case. That should simplify your code by removing the need to deal with your Poly<T> data type.

Comment: Given that "rank" is a term used to refer to dimensionality as I understand it, we could try "multi-rank" or "poly-rank" or something along those lines.

Comment: You can perhaps look at `R` for inspiration

Answer (score 6):

First, the difference between scalars and arrays isn't the number of elements, it's the dimensionality.
Scalars *are* arrays. Specifically, they're 0-dimensional arrays. So you'd just call all of them arrays.

But note that usually the focus isn't on what values the variable can *hold*, but what **operations** are allowed on the variable's potential values.

Some operations can generalize from 1 element to N elements, which seems to be what you want.

The CS-y term for this kind of operation is a "**vectorizing** operation".
The math term for this kind of operation is a "[**lifting** operation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting)".

Comment: "Scalars are arrays. Specifically, they're 0-dimensional arrays." --- out of curiosity, where does it come from?

Comment: @zerkms: Where does what come from?

Comment: The statement that scalar values are in fact 0d arrays. Not a type system/CT expert here, but it looks weird to me.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. As a matter of terminology, although in theory scalars are indeed 0-dimensional arrays, it seems odd and potentially misleading to therefore call scalars arrays. Could we call these maybe-scalars-maybe-non-zero-dimensional-arrays "polydimensional" values?

Comment: "although in theory" --- in what *theory*? What section of math/cs defines those as so?

Comment: @zerkms: Well this isn't a formal definition -- if you want to compare them you *have* to be willing to play a little loose with the terminology since one is a term from linear algebra and one is a term from programming. So we want a practical definition here. Now if you look at e.g. [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html#indexing), you see they treat scalars like 0-dimensional arrays -- you can even index them like you can index arrays. They're not really different.

Comment: @Mehrdad from type systems perspective this generalisation looks awkward to me. But it's just a personal opinion.

Comment: @torazaburo: I've never heard of that term.

Comment: @zerkms: I agree. I didn't mean it to be a formal/theoretical statement, since the question is quite informal/practical. (So e.g. I wouldn't have written this on CS.SE.)

Comment: @Mehrdad I know, I just made it up.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of anything like this and judging from the fact that the available JSON data types shown here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm do not mention anything related to such a data type, I'm betting that this is just smoke and mirrors implemented behind the scenes.

Scalar values and arrays are structured very differently.  Combining the two into a true data type would be self contradicting.  I'm betting that when the variable is instantiated a method is called somewhere to check the value for an array or scalar value, at which point one of two things takes place. 1- The data type is automatically set as an array and if a scalar is given, it is converted to an array of length 1 and whenever it is called behind the scenes an array is being accessed at index 0.  Or 2- The behind the scenes method checks what the data type that was passed in is and sets the same data type for the variable given before instantiation actually takes place.

If a MonoPoly *Mohn-O-Pohl-E* (if you will because I can't find anything else to call it and it looks like Monopoly) was a scalar and is set to an array data type at some point, the old value can be destroyed and a new one assigned with the same name but as an array.  This can happen vise versa and all this can be done behind the scenes as well, making this data type appear to house the description of a scalar along with an array.

Comment: The term MonoPoly is in reference to the fact that this data type is either one (Mono) or more than one (Poly)

Answer (score 1):

> is there any established terminology for this, or other good
>   suggestions?

I'm going to ignore "established terminology", and likely "good" as well, and make the following suggestions on a linguistic basis.  My personal choice, due to its sense of one or more rungs and its being the latin origin of *scalar*, would be:

**ladder**

Another possible noun:

**assemblage**

Like *constant*, I think the following adjectives are ripe to become nouns:

**inconstant** (similar to *incontinent*, "insufficient voluntary control" which seem to be what you described you have over this API issue.)

**transferable**

**indiscrete** (nicely homophonic to *indiscreet*)

**dual-purpose**

**multipurpose** (the adjective our schools love)

This might even be an oportunity to coin a new word:

**polyunary**

**versutility**  (my second favorite)

Comment: You left out "unconstant".

Answer (score 1):

Such functionality is likely *replacing* a scalar with an array when another element is "added" to a slot. AFAIK there's no term for this, so the question seems more like an English language question.

Try these:

- elastic scalar
- expandable scalar
- scarray (scalar/array)
- scalarray (another portmanteau)
- arrayable
- [tardis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS) (holds more than it appears to)

Comment: +1 for scarray which sounds like scarry... just like the whole scalar-array-mix idea is kind of scarry... ^^

Comment: @poby see last in new list :)